# penryn web starter kit by aristide benoist

Tags: javascript, animation, web, motion

I am using Aristide Benoist(https://www.aristidebenoist.com) Penryn starter web development kit - https://github.com/ariiiman/penryn-starter and am getting the following error on yarn dev - ErrorController.js is asking for Bundle/Common/Transition/Loader.js and Transition.js and Bundle/Common/Listeners/Listeners.js - has anyone run into this and have a solution?
Thank you!